# Using Python Variable in HTML / .format() for aws SES boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, boto

I am trying to add a variable inside  html body but its not working.

```
import boto3
SENDER = "xyz@abc.com"
RECIPIENT = "abc@abc.com"
AWS_REGION = "yyy"
SUBJECT = "Title"
BODY_HTML =
"""

<!doctype html> 
....
#somecode
<td>{email}</td>
</html>
BODY_HTML.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}").format(email="ffdks@ncsdk")
```

The variable is sent in email as {email} instead of ffdks@ncsdk.

And when replace is not there as:

```
BODY_HTML.format(email="ffdks@ncsdk")
```

It throws an error

BODY_HTML.format(email="email")
KeyError: '\n            font-family'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
BODY_HTML = """<!doctype html>
....
#somecode
<td>{email}</td>
</html>
"""
BODY_HTML = BODY_HTML.format(email="lakjsdfl"))
BODY_HTML.replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}")
```

Comment: it fthrows error!  print(BODY_HTML % "fbsak")
ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 607

Comment: @Luffli what if call email like smth like eeeemailllll and replace it on your desire email?BODY_HTML.replace(“eeeemailllll”, “you email”)?

Comment: @Luffli i've update the code, it works fine for me

Comment: @Luffli why do you replace { on {{ and then use format?first you need to use format and replace all of the brackets you need to repalace

Comment: It throws error KeyError: '\n font-family'

Comment: @Luffli try to replace '\n' on '', like BODY_HTML.replace("\n", "")

Comment: @Luffli would be great to take a look at the html

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_responsive

DOesnot work when gving variables.

Comment: @Luffli what if you replace with BODY_HTML = BODY_HTML.replace("{email}", "lakjsdfl")
and add {email} to the html?replace returns new copy of the string, so you need to set it to the variable

Comment: @Luffli as well, i know it's not the best sollution, try to remove % for {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}, and use <td>%s</td>

Comment: Thank you . I used jinja2 and it solved the problem as i had to do many other things.

Comment: @Luffli so my answer have not helper, right?